# When does path connectedness imply local path connectedness?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Are there any reasonable conditions one may impose on a path connected space such that it implies that it is locally path connected?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: in Eucledian spaces open+path connected $\imply$ locally path connected.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee In Eucledian space ($\Bbb R^n$) open already implies locally path connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn’t hold even for so nice spaces as compact subsets of the plane. To construct such a space $X$ consider a convergent sequence $X_0=\{(0,0)\}\cup \{(1/n,0):n\in\Bbb N\}$ and let $X$ consists of all segments connecting a point $(1,0)$ with points of $X_0$. Then the space $X$ is pathwise connected but not locally pathwise connected at a point $(0,0)$.

On the other hand, local pathwise connectedness is preserved by some operations with topological spaces, see the following exercise from Ryszard Engelkng’s “General topology”.

[image]

Comment: The quotient invariance is just what I needed, thank you very much